# Javascript computes string sent from Flask as integers

Tags: javascript, flask

I have a python flask function that renders a html page and sends dynamic variables to that html page:

`return render_template('index.html', start_date=str(start_date), end_date=str(end_date))`

In the html page, I am using javascript to read the `start_date` and `end_date` variables. However, since I am passing the dates in `mm/dd/yyyy` format which looks like `03/28/2016`. Javascript calculates the date value as a mathematical expression and returns back `0.0000531462585..` instead of returning `03/28/2016`.

Here is my JavaScript code to read date variables that flask renders to index.html:

`var startDate = {{ start_date }}`

How do I make sure that I get the date variables as String instead of the computed values?

Comment: Try escaping the `/` here. maybe that would work.

Comment: Hey I think the variable is holding the computed value from start. please post more surrounding code.

Comment: @Mr_Green I am printing out the variable right before I send it to the HTML page and its printing the date just fine, On top of that I am `str()` encoding the  var right before I send it to the HTML file from Flask. On the javascript side I am doing `var startDate = {{ start_date }}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var startDate = {{ start_date }};
```

is rendered as

```
var startDate = 03/28/2016;
```

That results in the math of 3 divided by 28 divided by 2016, or 0.0000531462585..

You can use [a couple of Flask and Jinja2 filters](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/templating/#standard-filters) to intelligently handle strings as strings and numbers as numbers.

```
var startDate = {{ start_date|tojson|safe }};
```

will render as

```
var startDate = '03/28/2016';
```

or something along those lines.

Comment: Awesome! That works :)

Comment: Ha. It's so hard to find old answers sometimes. `tojson` seems to give me the most fits.

Comment: @summerNight I think you can do this as well: `var startDate = "{{ start_date }}";
`

Comment: You can, and in this case it will work. But if `start_date` ended up being a string that contained quotes, you'd run into problems. `tojson` handles escaping them for you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to make sure `start_date` is a string.  Try `var startDate = start_date.toString();` instead.

Comment: I have this `var startDate = ({{ start_date }}).toString();` and it stills prints out a float.

Comment: Can you post how you're assigning `start_date` in the javascript code?

Comment: `var startDate = ({{ start_date }}).toString();`

Comment: It's coming from the Flask rendered template. So I could just use `{{ }}` to access it